# Delete Duplicate Data using Google Script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a script to automate deleting duplicate data based on column A. This is the current script I am using and it works.

```js
// This scripts works but deleting new data instead of old data
function removeDuplicates() {
 var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName(); 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var vA = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    var hA = vA[0];
    var hObj = {};
    hA.forEach(function(e, i) {
        hObj[e] = i;
    });
    var uA = [];
    var d = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= vA.length; i++) {
        if (uA.indexOf(vA[i][hObj['key']]) == -1) {
            uA.push(vA[i][hObj['key']]);
        } else {
            //sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++);
   sh.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - d);
   d++;
        }
    }
};
```

But this one is deleting the newly added row, what I want to achieve is it should delete the old duplicate row instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

In else part instead of using `i` which represent your current row, use the indexOf the row you want to delete. Delete it first and then push the new one into array

```js
// This scripts works but deleting new data instead of old data
function removeDuplicates() {
 var sheetName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName(); 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var vA = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    var hA = vA[0];
    var hObj = {};
    hA.forEach(function(e, i) {
        hObj[e] = i;
    });
    var uA = [];
    var d = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= vA.length; i++) {
        if (uA.indexOf(vA[i][hObj['key']]) == -1) {
            uA.push(vA[i][hObj['key']]);
        } else {
            //sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++);
            let j = uA.indexOf(vA[i][hObj['key']]);
   sh.deleteRow((parseInt(j)+1) - d);
   d++;
            uA.push(vA[i][hObj['key']]);
        }
    }
};
```